# MouseWheel event doesn't fire because TextBox steals Focus

Tags: c#

I was experimenting with the following code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseWheel);
}

private void Form1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text += "delta : " + e.Delta + "\r\n";
}
```

but the event never seemed to fire. Then I noticed that the Textbox got the focus as soon as the Form was shown, and, in fact, after I removed it, the event started working.

Now, the questions:

1. How can i get the event to fire whenever the Form is the top Window,
   even if I have a textarea on it?
2. Should i simply add the same event to the textarea or is there a
       simpler way to do it that i can't see?
3. Is there a way to wait for the "wheel rolling" to end before getting
           the event to fire? I need to exponentially increase an integer value
           based on how long the wheel has been rolled

Comment: Does this also happen when the mouse is positioned outside the textarea? You could override the MouseWheel event of the textarea object and have it call your form MouseWheel event.

Comment: Yes, it happens wherever the mouse is. Overriding the MouseWheel event of the textarea is the solution I had in mind, but i was hoping for something "simpler" : in a complex UI, i could have a lot of components stealing focus, that would leave me with the only option to override every single one?

Comment: And again, what if some of the components doesn't have a MouseWheel event but can get the focus?

Comment: Thats actually a solution, have a control that has no MouseWheel event take focus and your event does get called, while also keeping the scrolling in the textarea working!

Comment: That doesn't work : I've tried using a shockwave flash object in the same form instead of the textarea, and the result is quite "sad". The shockwave object gets the focus, and the mousewheel event is never fired

Comment: Ok maybe you should try it with a simple object, like a label, and otherwise just override the textbox event. Can you try if my solution solves your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Form1_MouseWheel to both the form and the textbox (or maybe only the textbox)
In this code all mouse wheel movements within one second after each other belong to the same series.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer second = new Timer();
    private int wheelMoves = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        second.Interval = 1000;
        second.Tick += new EventHandler(second_Tick);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void second_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        second.Stop();
        // DoStuff with wheelmoves.
        textBox1.Text = wheelMoves.ToString() + " " + (wheelMoves * wheelMoves).ToString();
        wheelMoves = 0;
    }

    void Form1_MouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // reset the timer.
        second.Stop();
        second.Start();
        // Count the number of times the wheel moved.
        wheelMoves++;
    }
}
```

Edit: If you add another control and have it steal focus you don't have to add the event handler to the textbox. This leaves the textbox scrolling function intact and also calls the  custom MouseWheel event.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely thing here is that the textbox is automatically stealing focus since the operating system may automatically assume that any mouse wheel scroll is directed to it (since it is the only available text edit control).

***Possible solutions:***

1. You could add the mousewheel event as you said to the textbox
2. You could force the create a textbox that can never receive focus by using `SetStyle` in a custom textbox class like this:

```
class unfocusableTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public unfocusableTextBox(){
               SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Those properties are readonly, adding a label and letting it take focus does help.